# Как получить данные, которые идут подряд

Tags: c#, linq

Есть `List<DB>`

```cs
class DB
{
    int id { get; set; }
    decimal win { get; set; }
    decimal credit { get; set; }
}
```

```
id     win     credit
1      10      100
2      12      105 
3      9       109
4      11      109
5      5       109
6      4       109
7      3       95
8      2       115
```

Как узнать с какого по какой индекс идут строки, с одинаковым `credit`. Допустим будет переменная `n`-количество совпадений идущие больше 4 раз подряд(>=). Вот как найти эти индексы?

В моем примере выше это с 3 по 6 строки

Comment: @aepot вчера тут был код

Comment: Он содержит ошибку, и я не знаю как ее исправить. Поэтому удалил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как один из вариантов, который написан на коленке:

```
int startIdex = -1;
var result = new List<(decimal Credit, Range Range)>();

for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
{
    var current = data[i];
    var next = i + 1 < data.Count ? data[i+1] : null;

    if (current.Credit == next?.Credit)
    {
        if (startIdex == -1)
            startIdex = i;
    }
    else
    {
        if (startIdex == -1)
        {
            result.Add((current.Credit, new Range(i, i+1)));
        }
        else
        {
            result.Add((current.Credit, new Range(startIdex, i+1)));
            startIdex = -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Поясняю что тут да как:

- `new List<(decimal Credit, Range Range)>` - тут все зависит от того, как вид вы хотите. Можно сделать класс, содержащий в себе эти данные, можно сделать `Dictionary`, у которого ключом будет `Range`, мне лично так было удобней)
- `for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)` - простой цикл, который даст текущий индекс (что нам и нужно).
- `var current = data[i];` - текущий объект.
- `var next = i + 1 < data.Count ? data[i+1] : null;` - следующий объект в коллекции. Если индекс за пределами, то возвращаем `NULL`.
- `if (current.Credit == next?.Credit)` - Если текущее значение и следующее равны, то...
- `if (startIdex == -1)` - дабы нам не менять каждую иттерацию стартовый индекс, есть эта проверка, которая меняет его значение лишь в тот момент, когда первый раз было найдено повторяющееся значение.
- блок `else` - тут думаю все понятно, если у нас текущее значение не повторяется со следующим, то мы проверяем изменение `startIndex`, если оно со стандартным значением `-1`, то просто добавляем новый объект, где `Range` будет от `i` до `i+1`, если же стартовый индекс был изменен, то добавляем уже нужный нам `Range` от `startIndex` до `i+1`, ну и сбрасываем этот индекс.

То есть, наша логика такая:

- Проверяем текущее и следующее значение

  - Если они равны, то записываем стартовый индекс.
  - Если они не равны, то:

    - Если индекс был изменен - добавляем в результат значение с `Range(стартовыйИндекс, текущий+1)`.
    - Если индекс не изменен - добавляем в результат значение с `Range(текущий, текущий+1)`.

В итоге мы получим примерно следующее:

```
(100, 0..1)
(105, 1..2)
(109, 2..6)
(95, 6..7)
(115, 7..8)
```

Сами данные:

```
0. 100
1. 105
2. 109
3. 109
4. 109
5. 109
6. 95
7. 115
```

И видим, что 109-е значение идет с 2 и до 6 индека (помним, что подсчет индексов в C# идет с 0!).

Тут можно провести еще различные улучшения, но саму суть думаю вы теперь поняли. Также выводимый результат смотрите сами какой вам нужен, к примеру, можете брать не индекс (`i`), а `id` из класса `db`, думаю труда вам это не составит.

А дальше уже поступайте с этими данными так, как вашей душе будет угодно, например:

```
var range = ranges.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Credit == 109);
var items = data[range.Range];
```

P.S. [Range](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges) были добавлены в C#8. Если по каким-то причинам вам это не подходит, то уж извиняйте, придется писать свои костыли.

<sup>Пример [онлайн](https://dotnetfiddle.net/r1seSs)</sup>